# R and time series graphing

Tags: r

I have a large data set named SE. `SE$YE` include years, whereas `SE$ANGR` is the annual growth of firms. Now I want to draw a time series graph for `SE$ANGR` with respect to `SE$YE` (years)

I have tried:

```
plot(SE$YE, SE$ANGR, type = "l", ylab = SE$ANGR, xlab = SE$YE)
```

My problem is that the graph is rough and not based on time series. lines are diamond shaped.

Comment: What you have said is your **goal**, what is your **question**? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far i have tried the following codes,

plot(SE$YE, SE$ANGR, type = "l", ylab = SE$ANGR, xlab = SE$YE)

issue with the code is that the graph is rough and not based on time series. lines are diamond shape.